# android Kotlin combine does not work with real time changes

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to observe changes of three different variables from three classes, and combine them into one list. but just to make things clear, in this example I will just try to print/log the changes of those variables.

**the problem is that I can see the variables are being changed, but I don't see the changes in the combine method, meaning I don't see the logs, the logic inside the combine block is not being triggerred.**

this is my variable in the three classes, all look pretty much tht same:

```
class NsdCustomService @Inject constructor(
) {
    companion object {
        val TAG = NsdCustomService::class.simpleName
    }

    ...

    private val _deviceFlow = MutableSharedFlow<DiscoveredDevice>()
    val deviceFlow = _deviceFlow.asSharedFlow().onEach {
        Log.d(TAG, "nsdCustomService emitting $it")
    }

    ...

    fun onServiceResolved(serviceInfo: NsdServiceInfo) {
        val mainActivityJob = Job()
        val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(mainActivityJob + Dispatchers.Main)
        coroutineScope.launch {
            val discoveredDevice = DiscoveredDevice(serviceInfo.serviceName,"temp")
            _deviceFlow.emit(discoveredDevice)
            Log.d(TAG, discoveredDevice.toString())
        }
    }
    
    ...
}
```

so I add values to `_deviceFlow` from inside a coroutine, I do it like this in all the three classes.

Now I have a fourth class where I want to combine and log all those changes. so I do it like this:

```
class DiscoveryService @Inject constructor(
    private val ssdpCustomService: SsdpCustomService,
    private val nsdCustomService: NsdCustomService,
    private val subnetDiscoveryService: SubnetDiscoveryService
) {

   ...
   
    init {
        val mainActivityJob = Job()
        val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(mainActivityJob + Dispatchers.Main)

        combine(
            ssdpCustomService.deviceFlow,
            nsdCustomService.deviceFlow,
            subnetDiscoveryService.deviceFlow
        ) { it ->
            Log.d(TAG, "LOG SOMETHING")
        }.onEach {
            Log.d(TAG, "LOG SOMETHING")
        }.launchIn(coroutineScope)
    }

   ...
}
```

I would expect that `LOG SOMETHING` will be logged everytime there is a change in one of the flows, but nothing happens, even though I can see other logs when there is change.

what am I missing?

**BUT**, I run a continusly methods to search for devices, and I don't want to stop them until the user exits the screen, so the flow is not suppose to complete, and I want to listen to real live updates.

any idea what am I missing?
thanks

Comment: Are you sure all three flows emitted at least a single item? Combine won't emit anything until all combined flows provided some item.

Comment: @broot I see now, you are correct. one flow is not emitting values. is there a way to continue without waiting for it?

Comment: What do you expect to receive in place of a missing item? Note that 'combine' produces a tuple of three items, so it can't produce anything until it gets an item from each flow.

Comment: That ChatGPT quote is complete nonsense. `combine` doesn't wait for flows to complete. If it did, it could only ever emit a single item, so it wouldn't be much of a Flow. In practice, most use cases for flows are for flows that *never* complete. `combine` only waits for flows to emit at least once each. Content from GPT is currently banned (because of confidently incorrect info like this) so you should remove the quote from your question to avoid the risk of your question being closed. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1).

Comment: Also, I see all your flows are some kinds of devices flows. If all your flows are of the same type, you simply need a single "flat" flow of all of them and you don't care what was the source flow, then you probably need `merge()`, not `combine()`.